# How to I call the "Read value from XML file" action from custom code?

Tags: install4j

The title says it all - I need to refactor multiple mini-actions into a single coherent piece of custom code, and to keep the refactoring under control, I want to stick with Install4J Actions as far as possible.
I checked the type hierarchy below `com.install4j.api.actions.Action` but found nothing XML-related.

BTW eventually the installer will have to call the "Replace text in XML files" action as well.
I.e. I'll appreciate any hints for a general strategy to find any action, given the name shown in the "Select an installation Action" dialog or in the "Screens & Actions" section of the Install4J GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name of the action can be seen in the .install4j project file. For example, for the "Read value from XML file", the class name is

```
com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.xml.XPathReadAction
```

You can instantiate it in custom code and execute it via

```
action.install(context);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `XPathReadAction` is not in `org.sonatype.install4j:i4jruntime`.

Comment: Update: I have version `org.sonatype.install4j:i4jruntime:5.1.14` here. I'll be glad to upgrade if that helps, though we're still in i4j 7.0.12 which may limit our runtime upgrade choices.

Comment: You would have to use the 7.0.12 runtime, then, not the 5.1.14 runtime. The Maven dependency is not a Sonatype artifact, you can find the correct coordinates at https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/

Comment: Ah right. I found the runtime in our corporate repo, which somebody uploaded a while ago, and I didn't check whether it is even up-to-date - the artifact is a stand-in for what the actual runtime provides, anyway.

Comment: Is install4j-runtime freely redistributable? (This has an impact on how much Red Tape is required to get it mirrored into our Artifactory.)

Comment: Yes, it is freely redistributable.